# React: looping over two different APIs doesn't seem to work.

Tags: javascript, json, api, loops, reactjs

Hi I have these mock APIs:

> Comments: https://api.myjson.com/bins/17g1r
>
> Posts: https://api.myjson.com/bins/2ec13

And I want to loop over Posts API and Comments API to get the number of comments each posts has based on the postId in the comments API in number. I tried to do this but it just returns a single object with data and others as nothing.
Here is part of the Component:

```
  postComments(comments, posts) {
    for (var key in comments) {
      const obj = comments[key];
        return posts.map((post, i) => {
              return <PostDisplay
                      key={i}
                      {...post}
                      commentLength={ obj.postId === post.id ? obj : '' }
                    />;
        })
    }
  }
```

The `commentLength` prop when console.logged returns this:

```
Object {id: 1, text: "Praesentium ut qui facere aliquid.", user: "keltonabshire", postId: 60297}
16
```

The `Object` is the only result it is passing and the `16` is the empty string I'm passing to `commentLength` on the `PostDisplay` component.

However I want to be able to render the `PostDisplay` component and also get the number of `comments` this particular `post` has using `postId`.

I have the `PostDisplay` working but the `commentsLength` is not all of the `posts` related to each component.

Thanks

Comment: if the `comments` object has, let's say, three keys, how many times do you think your `for in` loop will run the way you have written it?

Comment: Oh it's an array, well same question, if you have 3 comments, how many times will your `for..in` loop run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the comments length of particular post? You may no need to loop comments first, try this:

```
postComments(comments, posts) {

     return posts.map((post, i) => {
           return <PostDisplay
                   key={i}
                   {...post}
                   commentLength={ comments.filter(comment => comment.postId === post.id).length }
                 />;
     })
 }
```

Comment: How many times do you think the `for in` loop will run this way?

Comment: You're on the right track, but explain what you're doing and lose the `for..in` loop that's clearly broken.

Comment: May not need loop `comments`, just remove it.

Comment: @huachengzan Jesus, I didn't think of using filter and that inside of a prop too. I was having issue with how many times the for...in loop was running but this is the best one as it's immutable in a way. Cheers